# Redshift Table - Find Last Date of Query on a Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, database-administration

I am trying to clean up my small database and trying to see **when the last time some of the tables were actually queried** but cannot seem to find any documentation on how to do this. I can get the listing of all of the tables in my schema and the sizes, but cannot identify what might be stale before polling my users.

Does anyone know of a way to get the last date that a table was used/queried in redshift?

```
select
    schema,  
    "table",
     size as GB
from svv_table_info
    where schema = 'measure' or schema = 'mphd' or schema = 'offer'
order by schema asc;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can see when the table was last scanned in `stl_scan`. Almost all select queries will scan. The following is taken from: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_extended_table_info.sql As you've noted the history is only held for a limited period.

```
SELECT tbl,
       MAX(endtime) last_scan,
       Nvl(COUNT(DISTINCT query || LPAD(segment,3,'0')),0) num_scans
FROM stl_scan s
WHERE s.userid > 1
AND   s.tbl IN (SELECT oid FROM tbl_ids)
GROUP BY tbl
```

Comment: tbl_ids does not exist at least in my db

Answer (score -1):

You will quite possible have to parse entries in [`STL_QUERYTEXT`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERYTEXT.html), which stores SQL queries.

It might be easier to parse [`STL_EXPLAIN`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_EXPLAIN.html).

Both of these tables can be joined back to [`STL_QUERY`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html) to obtain a time when the query was executed.

Comment: However the STL tables only hold 2-5 days worth of history, so this will only tell you if it was queried recently. You might need to start unloading the STL tables into S3 files (Amazon's recommended approach) and then loading them into your own query history tables and running this for a while to collect the necessary amount of data to work out which tables are not being queried in your database.

Comment: @Nathan do you have any resources from amazon where they recommend that approach? Thank you!

Comment: What I was referring to (sorry, I should have been more specific) is enabling Database Audit Logging, which writes query activity to S3. To analyse these logs you might want read the logs back into Redshift, or create a Spectrum table over them (or use some other tool). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/db-auditing.html